# Remove all Untracked from files

Tags: git, github, git-untracked

Today I tried a bit with github and uploading. I did a test upload to git which did work. Now, when I start a new project I see everywhere an U after my file. How do I get rid off all the U's without deleting the files?

All my code is in the following folder: C:\Code
The code folder I uploaded to github was: C:\Code\adobe

[image: Link to the image]

**UPDATED**

By using the following command I removed all the Untracked files:
**rm -rf .git**

Comment: you should probably go through the basic git training somewhere like https://www.codecademy.com/learn/learn-git.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

By using the following command, I removed all the Untracked files: **rm -rf .git**

Answer (score 1):

To get those files to not show the `U` (meaning Untracked) after them you either need to add them to the tracked files in the git repo by adding and committing them or add them to the ignored files in the `.gitignore` file

Comment: @waddupxnxxx, take a look at this article:  https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/saving-changes/gitignore

Comment: Like I said I recommend going through a bit of git training, codeacademy is a decent place to start: https://www.codecademy.com/learn/learn-git. Also, the above link about .`gitignore` files is a great start for your reading/learning :D

Comment: I will! Ive edited my question. but do i need to add everywhere a gitignore file? @DrCord

Comment: typically in simple implementations a single `.gitignore` file is added at the root of your project.